# rails + angular upvoting comments through json not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, heroku

I am working on a rails app with posts and comments. right now it renders and API, and that API is accessed using angular.

right now everything is working but the upvoting feature. I keep getting a `422` error and I have no idea why. I am giving it the right route on angular, my controller on the rails side looks good, etc, but I am still getting the error: `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Here is my angular code

**service.js**

```
upvoteComment: function(postId, commentId, callback) {
$http({
  url: 'https://url.com/posts/' + postId + '/comments/' + commentId + '/upvote.json',
  method: 'PUT',
  data: { comment_id: commentId, post_id: postId }
}).success(function(response) {
  callback(response);
}).error(function(error) {
  callback(error);
 })
}
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.upvoteComment = function(postId, commentId) {
  PostService.upvoteComment(postId, commentId, function(data) {
    console.log("inside upvoteComment");
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

**view.js**

```
<ul ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
  <li>{{comment.body}}</li>
  <span>{{comment.upvotes}}</span>
  <button ng-click="upvoteComment(post.post.id, comment.id)">upvote</button>
</ul>
```

**rails controller**

```
def upvote
    comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    comment.upvote += 1
    if comment.save
      render json: comment.to_json, status: 200
    else
      render json: comment.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

**rails routes**

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy] do
      put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
    end
  end
```

This seems to be relatively straight forward, but I am not getting any errors from heroku about why it's rendering the `422`. If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Just a hint: have you tried creating an object (say "toPut") and append the commentId and postId as properties to that object?  Hence you'll have to send just the object itself in the data part of the http.put call.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to just add this to the application controller: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`. After that, everything works fine now.